# iPhone:What does (BOOL)isPad method describe?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am unable to get clear idea about the following method:

```
- (BOOL) isPad {    
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
#else
    return NO;
#endif
}
```

Actually for iPad applications this method is used but I don't understand that this method actually does, so if anyone could explain it in detail it would be very helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method simply checks if the `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` macro has been defined.

If it is available, it checks to see whether the macro is equal to `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`. If the comparison is true, it returns YES, otherwise if will return NO.

If the macro has not been defined, it means you are running iOS < 3.2 so it is definitely not an iPad.

For documentation, see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, tells you whether the current device that your app is running on is an iPad or not. Returns YES for iPad 1 & 2, and NO for iPhones and iPods.

Comment: I understand that but I want to know   #ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
#else
    return NO;
#endif
actually says...

Answer (score 0):

The #ifdef is the pre-compiler checking to see if a variable UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM is defined and then if it is defined as UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad. If it is defined as UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad that means it is being compiled for the iPad and returns YES, otherwise it returns NO.